# Formatting a GridView BoundField so Excel will not convert text to date

Tags: c#, excel, gridview

I am using C# to programmatically generate an excel file using GridView and BoundFields.  Right now it keeps converting certain values to dates rather than keeping them as pure text.

I want them to stay as they are returned from the DB, with no conversion from Excel. I have explored several options but I can't seem to get around this conversion.

This is going directly to a file.

The BoundField with the issue is "ReportNumber". Thank You for any help you all can provide.

Code Snippet:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AFDOJClosed2Excel(byte[] Data, string Reporting_Year)
{

    try
    {
        DataTable dt = GetAFDOJClosed(Reporting_Year);//your datatable
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = "Case_Number ASC";

        DataTable sortedDT = dv.ToTable();

        dt = sortedDT;

        GridView excel = new GridView();
        excel.DataSource = dt;
        excel.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        //Explicitly Create bound fields

        BoundField CaseNumber = new BoundField();
        CaseNumber.HeaderText = "Case Number";
        CaseNumber.DataField = "Case_Number";
        excel.Columns.Add(CaseNumber);

        BoundField Docket = new BoundField();
        Docket.HeaderText = "Docket";
        Docket.DataField = "Docket";
        excel.Columns.Add(Docket);

        BoundField AgencyName = new BoundField();
        AgencyName.HeaderText = "Agency Name";
        AgencyName.DataField = "Agency_Name";
        excel.Columns.Add(AgencyName);


        BoundField ReportNumber = new BoundField();
        ReportNumber.HeaderText = "Report Number";
        ReportNumber.DataField = "Report_Number";
        excel.Columns.Add(ReportNumber);


        BoundField ClosedDate = new BoundField();
        ClosedDate.HeaderText = "Closed Date";
        ClosedDate.DataField = "Closed_Date";
        ClosedDate.DataFormatString = "{0:d}";
        excel.Columns.Add(ClosedDate);

        BoundField TotalDisbursed = new BoundField();
        TotalDisbursed.HeaderText = "Total Disbursed";
        TotalDisbursed.DataField = "Total_Disbursed";
        TotalDisbursed.DataFormatString = "{0:C}";
        excel.Columns.Add(TotalDisbursed);

        excel.DataBind();


        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=AFDOJClosed" + Reporting_Year + ".xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        excel.RenderControl(htw);

        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();

        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel applies its own formatting rules based on the content of the cell if there is no specific data/formatting meta associated with it (e.g., format as Text, Number, Date/Time, etc).

Your code takes a `GridView` and effectively write out the grid data directly to the response stream. As far as the generated file is concerned, the dates are in cells of type "General" and Excel will apply the default formatting rules.

In order to have control of the data type associated with the cells, you'll need to use a library that interacts with the Excel data more explicitly rather than relying on a conversion mechanism as with the code above. A fairly straight forward library in NuGet is [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/4.5.0.1-beta) which we've used for exactly the reasons you've outlined above.

To apply a specific date format to a cell, you can use something like the following;

```
 ws.Cells["A3"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd";
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes adding formatting in the example seems to work OK. Its just the opposite that is the issue, formatting when I don't want to.  I will try the EPPlus suggestion.

Comment: @JGrant I get that you don't want it to format but I couldn't determine your intended data format from the code. The sample there is just to show it can be set to the desired format and not what Excel decides.

Comment: I just wanted it to be left alone, it is a string of numbers with the dash in the 3rd position. Excel only converts the values that start with a "0". I know its because it is interpreting 07 as July. I appreciate the insight. To me its just odd that you can't indicate the format for plain text. Or some switch to say "don't touch"

Comment: I just grabbed the EPPlus package, I cut so many lines of code out with that. And I get the formatting I want. Thank you again.